# Share Instagram photos possible?

Tags: javascript, php, api, instagram

I am currently developing a webapp for a friend of mine and he asked me if it would be possible to let people share Instagram photos that he placed on the site.

So basically he puts some photos from Instagram on his page and viewers should be able to share that picture on Instagram.

Answer (score 3):

**No.** From the API documentation;

https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/

> At this time, uploading via the API is not possible. We made a
>   conscious choice not to add this for the following reasons:
>
> Instagram is about your life on the go – we hope to encourage photos
>   from within the app. We want to fight spam & low quality photos. Once
>   we allow uploading from other sources, it's harder to control what
>   comes into the Instagram ecosystem. All this being said, we're working
>   on ways to ensure users have a consistent and high-quality experience
>   on our platform.

Comment: Isn't this about uploading an image? The image itself wont be uploaded. It's just about other people sharing that picture on his/her instagram account. Like sharing something on facebook.
Dont know if this is also 'not allowed'? :)

Comment: Yes you are right that this is about uploading but I just tried embedding an Instagram image (if that's how you plan to show images) and no share button shows up in the embed either.

Comment: Ah alright, well that's unfortunate. Thanks for your help anyways! :-D

Comment: There is no 'share' options on Instagram either. At least on the web app.